# Fedora 6, root has internet access, but new user does not

Tags: fedora

I have a machine running Fedora 6.  I can log on as root, open Firefox, and access the internet.  I created a new user account and a VNC for the user.  I can log into the VNC, but when I try to open Firefox, I do not  have any internet access.  Similarly, ping, traceroute, etc. do not work.

What do I need to do to allow a new user to have internet access?

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 3):

Users by default should have Internet access. Something is misconfigured. In what way do things "not work"? What are the error messages?

But really, the most important thing is: please, *please* upgrade your Fedora. Fedora 14 was just released yesterday, and it's a great, solid release with a lot of polish. Meanwhile, Fedora Core 6 was end-of-life December 7th, 2007. The older software, including Firefox, contains some serious bugs which make it not safe to use on the Internet.

In general, Fedora releases have a lifespan of 13 months and should be upgraded at least every second release. If that doesn't work for you, please, please use CentOS (based on RHEL5) or Ubuntu LTS (the LTS designates a special "long term support" release).

And as a plus, the problem you're having will almost certainly go away with a clean new install.

Comment: I agree that this is a very old version of Fedora and should be replaced.  Unfortunately, I'm not the main user of this machine and the main user already is using it to test some other software (which shouldn't have any dependency on Fedora 6 vs Fedora 14).  Since he's in a major testing phase, I'm not sure he'll just let me reinstall everything on the box (especially since I'd be using it for a very different purpose).  Normally, I would have immediately upgraded, but I'm not sure that I can at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Check the permissions on `/etc/resolv.conf` and see if normal users can read them, and then ASAP upgrade to a newer Fedora release.